# SQL Server : string parse

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

So I have a function that splits a string based on a character provided. For example

```
person = "sam, 25;tony, 19"
```

If I use the `function(person, ';')` it'll return a table

```
resulting_table = "sam, 25"
                   "tony, 19"
```

Now I have another table and I wants to insert the index of ',' for each row in it. I am using

```
insert into dbo.test_table_1(index)  
   select 
       charindex(',', select * from dbo.fn_parse_function(@json_string, ';'));
```

It is giving me an error. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance

Comment: ***WHAT*** error?? We really cannot read your screen - nor your mind - you'll have to **TELL US!**

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be using SQL Server and you have a *table*-valued function.  Such a function should go in the `from` clause:

```
insert into dbo.test_table_1([index])
    select charindex(val, ',')
    from dbo.fn_parse_function(@json_string, ';') p1(val)
```

Note that `index` is a really bad name for a column, because it is clearly a SQL keyword.